# json vs xml annotations for mapkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I have been working on a maps application (iphone) originally I had my annotations set up to pull XML from google using their Places API. I'm having **3 issues**.

1. For my annotation info, I was going
   off of an example from Zen
   (http://www.zen-sign.com/finding-business-listings-and-displaying-with-mapkit-part-1/
   ) and he has it set up to do it by
   keyword, which wasn't really
   necessary for me ( but I used it
   anyway just to get a feel for
   getting the annotations) in the
   parser header he has:

   ```
   -(void) getBusinessListingsByKeyword:(NSString*)keyword atLat:(float)lat atLng:(float)lng;
   ```

   and in the the viewdidload of his
   view controller

   ```
   [locationsMap findLocationsByKeyword:@"Apple" ];
   ```

   I'm not sure how to move from the
   keyword parse version used in zen to
   something that just does it
   automatically (in the parser object- without the viewdidload in a different view controller if possible).

   Any advice on what to read/watch or
   sample code much appreciated
2. For places information
   Google isn't the only kid on the
   block and XML I hear comes in second
   to JSON. So I wanted to know what
   the best practice was for map
   annotations made from business
   information: JSON or XML?
3. The other issue I was having was
   only getting 10 annotations (I want
   to get 50 or more). So on top of
   your advice on using XML or JSON.
   How to I increase the amount of
   annotations I'm getting.

Sorry for making this 3 parts but again any tutorials (text of video) would be very helpful. (So far I've watched hegarty from Stanford, Larson from MATC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

Don't know what you mean by automaticaly. But if you want to launch the map on users current location here you have two methods you can use:

```
-(IBAction)goToCurrentLocation{
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] 
                            initWithLatitude:myMap.userLocation.coordinate.latitude
                            longitude:myMap.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    [self setCurrentLocation:location];
}

- (void)setCurrentLocation:(CLLocation *)location {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}};
    region.center = location.coordinate;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.15f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.15f;
    [self.myMap setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Second. I don't know what are the best practicies but I used json with this [jeson parser](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) for my app [ijustmadelove](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/i-just-made-love/id351636402?mt=8)

Three. There is no problem in getting more then 10 annotations on the map. You have to have an error or a limitation in your code.

Comment: Hi I just looked at your app.. amazing! anyway yeah I have current location already. My problem is that to call the keyword Zen does it from a viewcontroller and I want to be able to do it from the parser (object) itself so that I don't have to do use a keyword at all and I would just do a google call like ( http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Apple&mrt=yp&sll=26.1209,-80.1444&output=kml ) so I know a few of the pieces to the puzzle but not really where to put them. I'll check out the Json parser you mentioned. Thanks for info